Prevent this method from being called whenever user drags the view
I'm creating an offset view that can be dragged with dragGesture. The issue that I have is that on drawing, the method content() is being called while the offset view (custom bottom sheet) is being dragged. How can I prevent this? I want this view to be draggable like a bottom sheet and it should not call the content() unless there's a state change..
  public var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack { }
            .banner(data: $viewModel.bannerData, isPresented: $viewModel.showBanner)
            .offset(x: 0, y: -30)

        Spacer()

        VStack {
            if viewModel.showDragRect {
                VStack {
                    Spacer().frame(height: 4)
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                        .fill(.grayMidDark)
                        .frame(width: 42, height: 5)
                    Spacer().frame(height: 8)
                }
                .frame(width: Dimensions.screenWidth)
                .contentShape(Rectangle())
            }

                content(offsetViewState: viewModel.offsetViewState)
            Spacer()
        }

            
                    .background(.thinMaterial).opacity(0.8)  // Adds a blur effect
            
        )
        .cornerRadius(Dimensions.viewRoundCorners, corners: [.topLeft, .topRight])
        .frame(width: Dimensions.screenWidth, height: viewModel.offsetViewHeight)
        .offset(y: viewModel.offsetValue + dragOffset)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .updating($dragOffset) { value, state, _ in
                    state = value.translation.height
                }
                .onEnded { gesture in
                    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                    let newPosition = viewModel.offsetValue + gesture.translation.height
                    viewModel.setOffsetViewState(offsetViewState: viewModel.offsetViewState, offsetValue: newPosition, hasAnimation: false, stateChanged: false)
                    let velocity = gesture.velocity.height
                    let snapPosition = self.calculateSnapPosition(for: newPosition, dragAmount: gesture.translation.height, velocity: velocity)
                        viewModel.setOffsetViewState(offsetViewState: viewModel.offsetViewState, offsetValue: snapPosition, hasAnimation: true, stateChanged: false)
                }
            
        )
    }
}


private func content(offsetViewState: OffsetViewState) -> AnyView {
    print("THIS GETS PRINTED WHENEVER/WHILE I AM DRAGGING THE SHEET")
    switch offsetViewState{
    case .searchState:
        return AnyView(
            viewModel.createSearchZonesView()
        )
    case .zoneListState:
        return AnyView(
            viewModel.createSearchZonesView()
        )
    case .shortZoneListState:
        return AnyView(
            viewModel.createSearchZonesView()
        )
    case .zoneInfoState:
        return AnyView(
            viewModel.createZoneDetailsView(baseFlowModel: baseFlowModel)
        )
    case .shortZoneInfoState:
        return AnyView(
            viewModel.createZoneDetailsView(baseFlowModel: baseFlowModel)
        )
    default:
        return AnyView(
            viewModel.createSearchZonesView()
        )
    }
}


This needs a [mre]. Also, perhaps unrelated, but you shouldn't be using AnyView like that -- watch Demystify SwiftUI from WWDC for info on why

I would definitely be suspicious of the AnyView. It's very hard for SwiftUI to reason about things inside of an AnyView. Try removing that as a starting point and return some View which is the normal way to do this. But do note that the system is free to call body any time it likes, so it's up to you to ensure that body is cheap to compute. Even so, it's good to not invalidate if you can help it, and getting rid of AnyView is good first step. Then keep simplifying to see what is causing your invalidation.
